# FluentValidator CS0103 - The name 'request' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, fluentvalidation

I have a very strange issue with FluentValidator in that for only one validator I get an exception being thrown as per the image below.

The request comes into my endpoint here

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBankTransactions([FromRoute] Guid BankAccountId, [FromQuery] GetBankTransactionRequestModel model)
{
   //Ommited
}
```

As you can see in the image below I hit the breakpoint in the validator and then I get the message as you can see

> error CS0103: The name 'request' does not exist in the current context.

I have 6 other validators within the solution at the moment all of which work fine and throw the 400 Bad Request response when validation fails.

I have had a look at the various issues that people have had saying that this is an environmental issue. But if thats the case, why is it only affecting on validator which is in the same namespace as the rest and in the same assembly?

Code as seen in the image is

```
public class GetBankTransactionModelValidator : AbstractValidator<GetBankTransactionRequestModel>
{
    public GetBankTransactionModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(request => request.PageNumber).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

[image]

I would be very grateful for any and all help on how to resolve this.

Edit

```
[Fact]
public async Task ValidatePageNumberGreaterThanZero_ReturnsValid()
{
    var request = new GetBankTransactionRequestModel
    {
        PageNumber = 1
    };

    var result = await _sut.TestValidateAsync(request);
    result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.PageNumber);
}

[Fact]
public async Task ValidatePageNumberGreaterThanZero_ReturnsInvalid()
{
    var request = new GetBankTransactionRequestModel
    {
    };

    var result = await _sut.TestValidateAsync(request);
    result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.PageNumber);
}
```

Same thing happens in the unit tests too

Comment: try to put the return request.PageNumber in a code block and debug there, what does request consist of?

Comment: I'd write a unit test for that validator. Easier to debug, then.

Comment: @Fildor the same thing happens in the unit tests too

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal, can you please show me in an answer what you mean as the way the validator is written is as per the docs

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint within the lambda expression, not for the complete line. Is `request` an instance of `GetBankTransactionRequestModel`?

Comment: Request does not exist on the line itself, but inside the Func you provided. If you turn the Func into a block (`request => { ... }`), you can place a break point in it more easily

Comment: @Tvde1, doesnt compile when I try this

Comment: @mu88, same thing, no joy.

Comment: @SimonPrice,
it should look like this:
`request => { return request.PageNumber }`
and then you can put a breakpoint within that code block

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal yea, that doesnt compile, if you read the docs on fluent validation this is pretty the only way to set them up

Comment: Which version of FluentValidation are you using? If there is a newer version, try installing that. Or try rolling the version back a patch level or two.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've already rolled forward and backward from the version that originally the issue was found

Comment: This is very weird. Try deleting all cached NuGet packages using the command line: `nuget locals all -clear`. Maybe something just became corrupted. You could also try deleting everything in the `bin` and `obj` folders in the Visual Studio solution as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt sorry for the late response. Thats not a bad shout. I will try that in the morning and will let you know how I get on

Comment: @GregBurghardt, same result im afraid